# How to POST data to an HTTP endpoint using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, http, http-post, aws-lambda

I am New to AWS Lambda
I was trying to POST a simple data from AWS data to HTTP endpoint, but i am unable to do that.
I was using NodeJs language.
And I want the POST method to be done using *http* module not using *request* module.
How to solve this.

Comment: Any specific error, show what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use only the `http` module, you can start from this example:

```
const http = require('http');

const requestBody = 'your=post&content=here';
const options = {
    host: 'httpbin.org',
    path: '/post',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': requestBody.length
    }
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    var responseString = '';

    res.on('data', function (data) {
        responseString += data;
        // save all the data from response
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(responseString);
        // print to console when response ends
    });
});
req.write(requestBody);
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to us the native HTTP module because you don't know how to include an external module. Since this is probably the case, take the time to read this article by AWS [Creating a Deployment Package (Node.js)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).

It should help you understand how to work with AWS Lambda, NodeJS and external modules.