# How to run a script outside the src folder in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My directory is as such:

```
├Script.js
|
├public/
|     └...
└src/
   └ App.js
```

and inside App.js I'm trying to invoke the `Script.js` as such:

```
import calculations from './../Script' 

...

onclick={()=>{calculations()}}
```

Script.js:

```
const calculations=()=>{...}

export default calculations;
```

but obviously it won't work, so how do I run a script on the server?
do I make a post request to the server? If so, how do I handle it? (like in express `app.post()`)

Comment: Why is the script outside of the src folder?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't want to send it to the client, it's a server side function

Comment: Are you using something like nextjs? Or is this what you're asking about?

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is what I'm asking about, currently I'm learning react

Comment: React doesn't have anything to do with server side scripts. You'll need to use node if you want to use javascript.

Comment: @evolutionxbox could you elaborate? I'm really new to all this

Comment: _"do I make a post request to the server"_ - yes. This is what node would do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925020/how-to-post-data-to-an-http-endpoint-using-nodejs

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm confused, I thought if react would start up a server on it's own then it should be able to handle incoming post requests as well (like express does)  are you saying I have to create a separate node.js server running to communicate with the react pages?

Comment: React is a front-end UI library. It starts a server only for development purposes, but it doesn't handle requests. https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/ may help?

Comment: @evolutionxbox well then I was right and now my question is redundant, should I use [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/) article as a reference to create 2 separate servers for backend and front end? or would you recommend a better other approach?

Comment: Libraries like [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) have been built to solve this issue. I don't have a preference since there are upsides and downsides to both approaches